# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'savedEtnia' of nullat FormItemsComponent.save ¿ Como soluciono el erro?

Tags: nodejs, angular

Me encuentro con el siguiente error, estoy usando angular, y me sale error en el método que tengo en el servicio, por lo que he leído, tengo que setear o algo por el estilo, pero no se como lo hago la verdad.

Al parecer el método del servicio esta null.

MI código HTML, donde solo tengo un `matDialog`  con un formulario de dos campos donde se pide elegir una opcional y un nombre, ahora no estoy pidiendo la opcional, solo el nombre en el segundo campo

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Nuevo Item</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="formReg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Elija una opción</mat-label>
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option value="0">Etnia</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="1">Religion</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="2">Orientación sexual</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="3">Estrato</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="4">Estado civil</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Número Documento</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] class="btn btn-danger mr-2">Cerrar</button>
    <button mat-button class="btn btn-success" (click)="save()">Guardar</button>
  </div>
```

Archivo componenTS tengo inyectado el servicio en el costructor, como debe de ir y utilizo el metodo del servicio para registrar la data, pero ahi es donde sale que esta null

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { EtniasService } from './../../../services/etnias.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-items',
  templateUrl: './form-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-items.component.scss']
})
export class FormItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  formReg: FormGroup;

  constructor( public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FormItemsComponent>,
               @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
               private service: EtniasService,
               public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.formReg = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get forms() {
    return this.formReg.controls;
  }

  save() {
      this.service.savedEtnia(this.formReg.value)
      .subscribe( res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
      );
  }
}
```

Archivo del servicio MI servicio normal, con su método `post`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Etnia } from '../models/etnia';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EtniasService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }



 savedEtnia(etnia) {
   return this.http.post(`${environment.api_url}etnias/new`, etnia, this.headers());
 }

savedReligion(religion) {
   this.http.post(`${environment.api_url}religion/new`, religion, this.headers());
}

saveEstadoC(estadoC) {
   this.http.post(`${environment.api_url}estado-cicvil/new`, estadoC, this.headers());
}

headers() {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.append('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
   headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Content-Type', undefined);
   const options = { headers, withCredentials: false };
   return options;
}

}
```

Aquí una imagen de mi error en tiempo de ejecución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta quitando `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)`

Comment: listo eso era....muchas gracias...de verdad que si, como no lo había notado :(

Comment: A todos nos ha pasado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu constructor deberia de quedar de esta manera:

```
constructor(
                            //Te falta esta parte
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FormItemsComponent>,       
    private service: EtniasService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder

) { }
```

Como lo tienes actualmente estas "sobreescribiendo" tu servicio con `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)`

Mas [informacion aqui](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)

Comment: eso es, pero por el momento lo voy dejar sin el MA_DIALOG_DATA